# Can I get theatrical and extended editions of The Lord of the Rings in one set?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, movie

I'd like to get the *The Lord of the Rings* motion picture trilogy on Blu-Ray.  My preference is to get both the theatrical and extended editions in one set.  Is this possible?  Does the extended edition discs give the option to watch the theatrical editions, as well?  OR do I have to buy both editions?

Comment: The extended DVD editions didn't provide a theatrical edition option, but I'm not sure about the Blu-Ray.

Comment: @thedaian could they have fit both on a DVD and still had acceptable quality (without flipping the disk)?

Comment: @Xantec Given that the extended edition DVDs had the movies split on two disks, I doubt it.

Comment: They _could_ release the theatrical and extended edition on a single blue ray disc, if I understand the format right. They would simply create a separate "program" for each version, one that would show all the chapters and one that would exclude the extended sections. In theory it shouldn't be too hard anyway.

Comment: There's a Limited Edition DVD set, but I don't think there's a Blu-Ray one (yet): [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Trilogy-Fellowship-Theatrical-Extended-Limited/dp/B000GTLR2A/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1323123037&sr=8-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just received the extended Blu-Ray set from Amazon last week and it only contains the extended version of each film.  Each film is split onto two blu-ray discs and pretty much all the special features are actually on DVD.

[http://www.amazon.com/Lord-Rings-Fellowship-Extended-Editions/dp/B0026L7H20/dp/B0026L7H20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026L7H20)

Comment: Well, stink. :-(